# How to validate pair uniqueness in array in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm developing CRUD for Laravel application for Tariff entity.
Tariff table has such structure for now:

```
--------------------------
|id | name | hint | price|
--------------------------
```

I also have many-to-many relation with services included in tariffs.
The binding table structure is:

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | tariff_id | service_id | type | value |
----------------------------------------------
```

On database level pair of **tariff_id & service_id** are unique (Specific tariff cannot have 2 same services: (1-1) & (1-1)).

I made vue table component for adding services to tarrifs and trying to validate this case using laravel validation rules.

Here is a piece of FormRequest data I get from table component

```
"id" => 3,
"services" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "service_id" => "2"
      "duration_type" => "0"
      "duration_value" => "1"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "service_id" => "3"
      "duration_type" => "0"
      "duration_value" => "2"
    ]
]
```

My validation rules for services are:

```
'services' => 'required|array',
    'services.*.service_id' => [
    'required',
    'string'
    ],
    'services.*.duration_type' => 'integer|min:0|max:1',
    'services.*.duration_value' => 'required|string',
```

**The question is: How do I check uniqueness for current service_id & tariff_id?**
I mean when I write something like **'services.*.service_id'** it's iterating somehow through my array of data so I need to compare current iteration's service_id to tariff_id.

Would be glad if someone can help me with this situation, mayber there's another way to make it work.
To prevent user insert non-unique data I put try catch block in my controller & when MySQL error happens controller just fires alert. It's working but feels cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using [the validation rule unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique)? Something like

```
'services.*.service_id' => [ 'required', 'string', 'unique:tariff_services,service_id' ]
```

where tariff_services is the name of the pivot table?

Comment: wow, that's actually helped me! so laconic solution! I just rename pivot table to **tariff_has_services** and it's working!

Comment: few minutes later I recognized that this rule doesn't allow any entries

Comment: I'm trying something like `"unique:tariff_has_services,service_id,NULL,id,tariff_id,1"` but it still doesn't work for me